# Weird looking square root on pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a simple `sqrt(x)` function and I get a weird looking one.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
        smooth, no markers, grid,
        domain=0:2,
        xmax=2, ymax=2,
        xmin=0, ymin=0]

        \addplot +[red] {x^2};
        \addplot +[blue]{sqrt(x)};
        \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm plotting it together with `x^2` and what I get is clearly not the inverse function:

[image: link]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see why this happens if you remove `no markers` from the `axis` options.  A quick fix is to have denser sampling near zero, with help from `samples at`. Personally I'd also not use `smooth`, the results aren't always that good.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
    no markers, grid,
    domain=0:2,
    xmax=2, ymax=2,
    xmin=0, ymin=0]

    \addplot +[red,samples=50] {x^2};
    \addplot +[blue,samples at={0,0.001,0.005,0.01,...,0.2,0.3,0.4,...,2}]{sqrt(x)};
    \addplot +[samples=2] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jagjordi If the the `sqrt` function is too hard to plot near `0`, one may also plot the *disingenuous* reciprocal `\addplot +[blue,samples=50] ({x^2},{x});`

Comment: @marsupilam, as I stated in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375348/95441) this is the best way to fix the problem easily in an "automated" way. Could you transfer your comment to an answer please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jut a quick question: what do the dots in `{0.01,...,0.2,0.3}` stand for? Thanks again

Comment: @jagjordi It completes the sequence of numbers, same as in `\foreach` loops. E.g. `0.5,1.5,...,4` is the same as `0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5`. More generally, in `x, y, ..., z`, `x` is the first number in the sequence, `y` is the second number, and `y - x` is the step. The sequence stops when it reaches `z`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Done !

Answer (score 5):

As Torbjørn states in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375341) the key is to increase the sampling density around x=0. But to my personal view stating the x samples *by hand* (using `samples at`) is the most inelegant way.

The simplest (good) solution is given by marsupilam in the [comment below Torbjørn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375337/w#comment928746_375341) which he hopefully will transfer into a real answer.

Here I present a *general* way to get unequal spacing and the "inequality" can be changed by simple changing the constant `a`. Applying the same method on a much more complex equation can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373820/95441.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use Lua for calculations
        % (this is not required though)
        compat=1.12,
        /pgf/declare function={
            % declare the main function(s)
            f(\x) = sqrt(\x);
            % state (or calculate) the lower and upper boundaries (the domain values)
            lb = 0;
            ub = 2;
            %
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            %%% nonlinear spacing: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/39140096/5776000>
            % "non-linearity factor"
            a = 2;
            % function to use for the nonlinear spacing
            Y(\x) = exp(a*\x);
            % rescale to former limits
            X(\x) = (Y(\x) - Y(lb))/(Y(ub) - Y(lb)) * (ub - lb) + lb;
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % just to show that also here the above constants/functions can be used
        xmin=lb,    xmax=ub,
        ymin=f(lb), ymax=ub,
        grid,
        % also use the constants for the domain, so there is only one place
        % where you need to change the values
        domain=lb:ub,
        smooth,
        no markers,     % <-- comment me to show where the x points are
    ]
        \addplot+ [mark=o]              {x^2};
        \addplot+ [samples=2]           {x};
        \addplot+ [mark=triangle,thick] {f(x)};
        \addplot+ [mark=square,green]   ({X(x)},{f(X(x))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

As requested by Stefan Pinnow, I expand my comment to an answer.

We just plot the original function `x|->x^2` twice :

- one normally,
- and once after applying the `x <-> y` symetry of the plane. This is the graph of the reciprocal

The output is the same as other answers above.

Here, I changed the original function to showcase that it still works for non-bijective functions...

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    declare function= 
    {
      myFunction(\x) = .5*\x + sin(90 * \x);    % for demo
      %myFunction(\x) = \x^2;                   % your function
    },
  ]
  \begin{axis} 
    [
      unit vector ratio = 1 1,
      no markers,
      grid,
      domain=0:2,
      xmax=2,
      ymax=2,
      xmin=0,
      ymin=0,
      samples=50,
    ]

    \addplot +[red] {myFunction(x)}; % shortcut for ({x},{myFunction(x)});
    \addplot +[blue] ({myFunction(x)},{x});
    \addplot +[samples=2] {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```