# How to draw multiple curves and name them?

Tags: pgfplots

I need to draw multiple curves illustrating run time but some of them aren't working besides I don't know how to name these curves in the figure .

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
    axis lines=center,
    axis line style=->]
    \addplot[->] expression[domain=0:10,samples=100]{x^(2)} ; 
  \addplot[->] expression[domain=0:10,samples=100]{\sqrt(x)} ;  
     \addplot[->] expression[domain=0:10,samples=100]{x!} ; 

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I still need to draw constant, logarithmic and exponential but for now how do I get the code to work and how do I get to have the names next to each curve? (Extra material explaining all of this would also be helpful)

Comment: Quick solution: `\sqrt(x)` = `x^(1/2)`.

Comment: @ebo, the ``\`` in `\sqrt` is the problem, which is not needed. So simply writing `sqrt(x)` is sufficient. But this only solved one problem ...

Comment: You could start by changing '\sqrt' to 'sqrt'. If you want to add labels, you could use the legend command, alternatively you could add a node, e.g.: addplot{sqrt(x)} node {y=...};

Comment: ... The second problem is that `10!` results in a number of the magnitude of `10^6` which is *much* bigger than the next smaller number of `10^2 = 100` and thus you will get an "dimension too large" error. And even *if* it would be plotted, you won't *see* the `100` compared to the `10^6`. So I suggest to simply reduce the domain of the faculty to 6 or 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see here what you need to know to start with pgfplots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=6.9,
    ymin=0,ymax=30,
    axis lines=center,
    axis line style=->]
    \addplot[dashed,red] expression[domain=0:5,samples=100]{(x)^2} ; \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
  \addplot[-,green] expression[domain=0:5,samples=100]{sqrt(x)} ;  \addlegendentry{$\sqrt{x}$}
     \addplot[dotted,blue] expression[domain=0:5,samples=100]{x!} ; \addlegendentry{$x!$}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As @Stefan Pinnow said the domain was too big for the factorial and I had to change it...

The result is here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you are not very precise in your question what you really want to achieve, so in my answer I am assuming that you want to stick to the given axis limits.

As already stated in the comments below the question, without changing "something" and only correcting `\sqrt(x)` with `sqrt(x)` you would get a "dimension to large" error because of the `x!` function yielding a value of the magnitude `10^6`, compared to the axis limit of `10`.

Also it is not clear *how* you want to "name the curves". If you meant adding a legend, than have a look at the [answer of koleygr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376126). If you wanted to add names *at* the plots itself, that is what I am presenting here. I also use the "hard" case here, adding the names "at the end of the plot", i.e. at `pos=1`. If the labels should appear somewhere "in the middle of the plot", feel free to add corresponding `pos` statements to the label `node`s.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code. (If still something should be unclear, please don't hesitate to ask.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /tikz/>=stealth,
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use Lua for calculations
        % (this is not required though)
        compat=1.12,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % please skip this block for now
        % (copied from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375348>)
        /pgf/declare function={
            % declare the main function(s)
            f(\x) = sqrt(\x);
            % state (or calculate) the lower and upper boundaries (the domain values)
            lb = 0;
            ub = 10;
            %
            % ---------------
            %%% nonlinear spacing: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/39140096>
            % "non-linearity factor"
            a = 0.4;
            % function to use for the nonlinear spacing
            Y(\x) = exp(a*\x);
            % rescale to former limits
            X(\x) = (Y(\x) - Y(lb))/(Y(ub) - Y(lb)) * (ub - lb) + lb;
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % use the above defined variables here as well, so you only have to
        % change them in one place, if you would like to change these values
        xmin=lb,xmax=ub,
        ymin=0,ymax=10,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->,
        % move common options here
        % also use the above defined variables here
        domain=lb:ub,
        % you don't want to show markers
        no markers,
        % show the plots "smoothly"
        smooth,
        % because the label nodes will be outside the axis "rectangle" they
        % would be clipped, so we disable clipping
        clip=false,
    ]
%        % Using these two functions have some downsides ...
%        \addplot+ [domain=0:4] {x^2};
%        \addplot {sqrt(x)};

        % Instead of increasing the number of samples "to make it look good",
        % we use nonlinear sampling instead.
        % (For more details have a look at <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375348>)
        \addplot ({X(x)},{f(X(x))})
            % add a label (node)
            % (the default position is at `pos=1.0`)
            node [right] {$\sqrt{x}$}
        ;

        % Because $x^2$ is the inverse function of $\sqrt{x}$ we simply
        % exchange the $x$ and $y$ arguments of the previous `\addplot'.
        % By doing that we also avoid that the function looks bad and we don't
        % have to increase the number of `samples'
        \addplot ({f(X(x))},{X(x)})
            node [above]{$x^2$}
        ;

        % Here we also use the minimalistic approach.
        \addplot+ [
            % Because values only change at integer x values, we can use
            % `const plot'.
            const plot,
            % $4!$ already yields $24$ and so we don't need a higher max
            % `domain' value.
            domain=0:4,
            % Use a number of samples that assures that also samples are at
            % integer x values to give a right result. This makes $5$ at minimum.
            samples=5,
            % So the plot stops at $y = 10$ use the following key--value.
            % (Otherwise, because we use `clip=false' the line would be drawn
            %  up to 24.)
            restrict y to domain*=0:10,
        ] {x!}
            node [above] {$x!$}
        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd be interested in a log-log plot ?

### The output

#### Brute plot

[image]

#### Restricted `y` domain

With `\addplot+[mark=none,const plot,restrict y to domain=0:42] {x!};`

Are displayed, only those values between `exp(0)=1` and `exp(42)~10^17`.

I think this is enough to bring the point home about the relative growths.

**Actually** : *setting `ymax` is better.*

[image]

### The code

#### Brute plot

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}
    [
      %domain=2:30,
      ymin=1,
      axis lines = center,
      samples at ={1,2,...,100},
      grid=both,
      legend entries={$y=x!$,$y=x^2$,$y=\sqrt{x}$},
      every axis legend/.append style=
      {
        at={(current axis.above origin)},
        anchor=north west, xshift=1cm, yshift=-1mm,
        draw=none,
        cells={anchor=west},
        %font=\scriptsize,
      }
    ]
    \addplot+[mark=none,const plot] {x!};
    \addplot+[mark=none] {x^2};
    \addplot+[mark=none] {sqrt(x)};
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Restricted domain

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}
    [
      height=13cm,
      ymin=1,
      ymax=exp(40),
      hide obscured x ticks=false,
      hide obscured y ticks=false,
      axis lines = center,
      samples at ={1,2,...,100},
      grid=both,
      legend entries={$y=x!$,$y=\exp(x)$,$y=x^2$,$y=\sqrt{x}$,$y=\ln(x)$},
      every axis legend/.append style=
      {
        at={(current axis.above origin)},
        anchor=north west, xshift=3mm, yshift=-1mm,
        draw=none,
        cells={anchor=west},
        %font=\scriptsize,
      },
    ]
    \addplot+[mark=none,const plot,] {x!}; 
    \addplot+[mark=none] {exp(x)}; 
    \addplot+[mark=none] {x^2};
    \addplot+[mark=none] {sqrt(x)};
    \addplot+[mark=none] {ln(x)}; 
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I insert this as part of exercise 1 , when I add \section{Introduction} after \begin{document} and I write something before \end{document} the layout is off

Comment: @G.Khalaf This failure is because my code is a `standalone` document (a LaTeX type for *pictures*). If you change the first line to `\documentclass{article}`. Otherwise, you can compile the code above to produce a pdf file, then use `\includegraphics{<theGeneratedPDF>}` inside your main LaTeX file containing your **exercice 1**