# tikz, \addplot with equation, discrete steps

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to change the discretization tikz uses in order to get a smoother graph.

```
 \documentclass[article]{standalone}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}  % loads newest improved settings

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[scale only axis, xlabel = x, xmin = 0, xmax = 4, ylabel = y,  ymax = 40, ymin = 0, ytick pos=left]



\addplot [black, domain=0:3.5] {25*x^0.2};

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \addplot [black, domain=0:3.5, **samples=100**] {25*x^0.2};

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: or `\addplot [black, domain=0:3.5, smooth] {25*x^0.2};` :-)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375337/

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thank you, works perfectly! I use samples=1000, with samples=100 I still get a little kink. @zarko, thank you! smooth doesn`t work for me, still a kink.

Comment: (@Zarko) Sophie, I think that Zarko's comment is a joke :).

Comment: oh ^^ :D I get it now

Comment: You can accept my answer if your problem is solved. This way the process comes to an end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Comment2Answer* :)

```
\addplot [black, domain=0:3.5, samples=100] {25*x^0.2};
```

The `samples` option of the `\addplot` command defines the number of supporting points (German *Stützstellen*).

[image]