# Spy TikZ library: an expansion of differents zoom

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

Starting from my [old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446725/truncated-at-the-top-of-the-graph-for-a-lorentzian-function) where I have modificated some parameters,
I have not understood the reason because the center of the spy is not in `$(4,3.5)$` but it is closer at the point `$(3.2,3)$` (this value is given by me after different compilations).

`\spy[green!70!black,size=2cm] on (3.2,3) in node [fill=white] at (8,1);`

After there is the main question:

Is it possible to have with the library of TikZ, `\usetikzlibrary{spy}`, a sequence of differents rectangular zoom as into this image with the same direction (it is taken from the book CALCULUS of JAMES STEWART 7th edition),

[image]

where is it possible to have the labels of the zoom as into this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59036/using-tikzlibrary-spy-without-magnifying-line-width-and-or-mark-size) (very great answer of the user @Tobi)?

[image]

Here I adding my MWE with the relative screenshot.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,amsmath,xcolor}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle=.5cm, magnification=3, size=.5cm, connect spies}]
    \tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=10pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=2pt
    }
    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
    \makeatother
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        xlabel={},
        ymin=-3,ymax=3,
        axis on top,
        legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}] 
       \begin{scope}
       \spy[green!70!black,size=2cm] on (3.2,3) in node [fill=white] at (8,1);
       \end{scope}
    \addplot[color=gray,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers you link to seem to say that they repeat the drawing, scale it and clip it. Within `pfgfplots` this may eventually lead to performance problems (even though not in such simple graphs), so one may want to use `\savebox`es and `path picture`s to arrive at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newsavebox\Axis
\begin{document}
\savebox\Axis{
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=pow(\x-1.5,3)-\x+3.5;}]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1,xmax=4,xlabel={$x$},xtick=\empty,
        ymin=-1,ymax=4,ylabel={$y$},ytick=\empty,
        axis lines=middle] 
    \addplot[color=cyan,thick,domain=-4:4,samples=51,smooth] {f(x)};
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,cyan] at (2.2,{f(2.2)}){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node{\usebox\Axis};
 \node[draw,minimum size=0.5cm,purple] (s1) at (1,0.2){};
 \node[draw,minimum size=1cm,purple,
 path picture={\path (-1*2,-0.2*2) node[scale=2]{\usebox\Axis};}] (s1')
 at (2,0.2){};
 \node[draw,minimum size=0.5cm,purple] (s2) at (2,0.2){};
 \node[draw,minimum size=1cm,purple,
 path picture={\path (-1*3,-0.2*3) node[scale=3]{\usebox\Axis};}] (s2')
 at (3.5,0.2){};
 \foreach \X in {1,2}
 {\draw[dashed,purple] (s\X.north west) -- (s\X'.north west)
 (s\X.south west) -- (s\X'.south west);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that this can be made more user friendly. However, as I had to more or less completely abandon your code in order to arrive at something reminiscent of what I think the target output is, I add this as version 0.1.

Well, seems not what you want, but it is also not so easy to see what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newsavebox\Axis
\begin{document}
\savebox\Axis{
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=pow(\x-1.5,3)-\x+3.5;}]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1,xmax=4,xlabel={$x$},xtick=\empty,
        ymin=-1,ymax=4,ylabel={$y$},ytick=\empty,
        axis lines=middle] 
    \addplot[color=cyan,thick,domain=-4:4,samples=51,smooth] {f(x)};
    \path (0,0) coordinate (O) (2.2,{f(2.2)}) node[circle,fill,inner
    sep=1.5pt,cyan] (a){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy node/.style={draw=purple,minimum size=#1*0.5cm,
 path picture={{\path (-#1*\myx,-#1*\myy) node[scale=#1]{\usebox\Axis};}}}]
 \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\usebox\Axis};
 \path let \p1=($(a.center)-(current axis.center)$) in \pgfextra{\xdef\myx{\x1}\xdef\myy{\y1}}
 (\p1) coordinate (a');
 \node[draw,minimum size=0.5cm,purple] (s1) at (a'){};
 \node[spy node=2] (s1') at  ($(a')+(1,0)$){};
 \node[spy node=4] (s4') at  ($(a')+(3,0)$){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent work.